# Probability question of multiple family winners

Tags: probability

My family of 4 attended an event with 44 additional people in the room. There was a raffle drawing where only five prizes were given. Once a person's name is drawn from the hat, that name is removed for the next drawing. Three of our family members names were drawn out of the hat. What are the odds of that happening?

Comment: this question falls under the category: Hypergeometric Probability

Answer (score 2):

The are ${4\choose 3}$ ways to choose $3$ members of your family, ${44\choose 2}$ ways to choose two of the other people in the room, and ${48\choose 5}$ ways to choose five people from $48$, so the probability is 
$${{4\choose 3}{44\choose2}\over{48\choose5}}\approx.00221$$

This equates to odds of about $903$ to $2$ against.

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 members, you choose any 3 of your family members and rest 2 of the other guests.

The probability that one of your family members is chosen out of the 48 total guests = $\frac{4}{48}$

The probability that the second one of your family members is chosen out of the remaining 47 total guests =$\frac{3}{47}$

The probability that third one of your family members is chosen out of the rest 47 total guests =$\frac{2}{46}$

 
Now, we need to make sure that the last family member is not chosen, so the probability of choosing the other 2 persons(that are not your family members)=
$\frac{44}{45}$ * $\frac{43}{44}$

SO, total probability = $\frac{4}{48}$ $\frac{3}{47}$ $\frac{2}{46}$ $\frac{44}{45}$ $\frac{43}{44}$ = **0.000221**

Comment: What you have calculated is the probability that the prizes were awarded in that particular order.  However, the three family members could have been in any three of the five positions, which you have not accounted for.

Comment: I'll be interested to hear any other feedback. I'm not a mathematician but it seems like the odds would be longer than 450 to one (the first answer above). Thanks!